# Unable to add domain. It may already be registered to another project

Tags: angular, firebase, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

I am not able to add my domain to firebase web app as it says "Unable to add domain. It may already be registered to another project."

I have already tried creating a new project and adding to the same domain but the error still says the same.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that the domain you're trying to use with your Firebase project is already associated with another Firebase project. It's impossible to use the exact same domain with multiple projects, as Firebase would have no way to determine what resources to serve.

To allow linking the domain to the new project, you must first delete it from the existing domain through the [Firebase hosting console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/z2a-_/hosting/main). Once you've done that, you can start the process of linking the domain to the new project.

Comment: I accidenlty closed the console window before adding the A records after ownership verification...Now I can neither restart the process nor remove the domain as it never got linked.....I am stuck

Comment: Please [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.